# Ternary random generator from coinflip

Tags: probability, random, binary

Provided a coinflip generator (a function that can be called to provide an output of either `1` or `0` with equal probability of $1/2$), is it possible to construct a function that would

1. yield either `a`, `b` or `c` with equal probability of $1/3$, and
2. have well-defined memory requirements, runtime and guaranteed termination? *(This point rules out running the coinflip two times for 4 outcomes and assigning one of the outcomes to re-run, because that is no longer guaranteed to terminate.)*

This thought experiment appeared simple at first, but having given it some thought, I'm not sure this is possible, but I can't prove either case.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3340212/.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. When you flip the coin $n$ times, you have $2^n$ equiprobable results. You want to divide them up equally among the $3$ outcomes, but $2^n$ is not divisible by $3$. Thus, no matter how often you throw the coin and no matter how you assign the outcomes, there will always be $1$ or $2$ outcomes left over. Thus, an algorithm that yields a probability of exactly $\frac13$ cannot be guaranteed to terminate; you can only minimize the expected number of coin flips you need to generate.

Comment: I have also come up with this, but was not sure this rules it out completely - can this be considered proof?

Comment: I was always curious about a slightly relaxed problem, that is, if I just require finite termination (arbitrary number of steps) for **all** inputs (not just ae.) is it possible to define an algorithm that satisfies 1. in the question? Seems tantalisingly doable.